# How to get the type of a generic parameter by reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, methodinfo, generic-method

I need to get the generic type of an generic parameter by reflection. But the real type, and not the type { Name="T" ; FullName=null }

```
public void Sample<T>(T i, object o)
{
    MethodBase basee = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
    Type[] types = basee.GetGenericArguments();
}
```

but i can't use typeof(T), because i'm using reflection

Is there a way (using reflection) to get type type of generic arguments.

```
// in this case i should get (Type) { Name="Int32" ; FullName="System.Int32" }
myClassObj.Sample(10, new object());
```

In other therm, i whant to know how to call the method called by typeof(T) ex:

```
// in Il code I see that the compiler use:
// ldtoken !!T => this should get the RuntimeTypeHandle needed as parameter
// System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromHandle( ? ? ? );
```

How could i get the RuntimTypeHandle from a T generic arguments

Comment: Why can't you use `i.GetType()`? For that matter, why can't you use typeof(T)? That will tell you it's an int.

Comment: The value i could be null, and make crash ... :S

Comment: Fair enough. But why not typeof(T)?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the point of all this, but what about

```
public void Sample<T>(T i, object o)
{
  Type t = typeof(T);
  if (i != null)
  {
    t = i.GetType();
  }

  // Do whatever with t
  Console.WriteLine(t);
}
```

Then you've got the run time type (if there is an object), otherwise you've got the static type.

Comment: +1 (and congrats on 2000 points), but I would suggest a more compact expression: `Type t = i == null ? typeof(T) : i.GetType();`.